# Why is my Laravel 'show' controller not passing along the variable?

Tags: laravel, variables, controller, routes, show

I currently have

```
GET|HEAD      forum/{forum}       App\Http\Controllers\ForumController@show
```

and

```
Route::resource('/forum', 'ThreadController');
```

and

```
public function show(Thread $thread)
    {
      return $thread;
    }
```

but when I go to 'forum/152' (post #152 in MySQL database) for example, the page only displays a blank '[]' array. How can I fix this so that the selected item shows? Thank you. :)

Comment: You can't use `{forum}` and expect to resolve an instance of `Thread` through implicit route model binding. Either change it to `forum/{thread}` or change the controller to `Forum $forum`.

Comment: that solved it. thanks Ohgodwhy :)

Comment: You should add this as answer @Ohgodwhy